# Using SQL to query Spanner with timestamp bounds

Tags: timestamp, google-cloud-platform, bounds, google-cloud-spanner

Can I use the Google Cloud Spanner Console to perform a [read operation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reads) with SQL using a [timestamp bound](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/timestamp-bounds)?

This seems to be possible using the SDKs, but I have not found a way to do this using [SQL through the Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-syntax?hl=en_US&_ga=2.36903264.-1511222537.1516662310).

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: You say that with the SDKs it seems to be possible to run the reads you want with timestamp bounds. Could you please indicate which SDKs you are talking about?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it's not supported through sql, using clients is the way to go..

For example in go: https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/spanner#example-ReadOnlyTransaction-WithTimestampBound